# Using custom-made makefile in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, cmake

If this question is not suitable here, please let me know.

I am trying to set up an environment in Eclipse to use a custom-built makefile generated by cmake instead of the built-in builders in eclipse. I have tried all the recommended settings but there is still no joy.

I create a new project with New->C++ Project->Makefile project->Empty Project and changed the location from default to the location where my project is.

In project->Properties->C/C++Build, I un-tick the "use default build command" and put the path where my makefile is. I also un-tick "Generate Makefiles automatically".

[image]

I have tried many different commands but I am receiving errors like "No rule to make target '/Makefile'. Stop"

I am surely missing out on something. If anyone has any knowledge about how to do this it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When I make a `Makefile` project I don't need to play with any settings. I generate the `Makefile` (I use autotools but should not change anything). Then I open the Makefile in the editor and on the right window I select the `Outline` tab. Then just select and add the *make targets* you want (usually all, clean, install and uninstall). Then switch to the `Make Target` tab (next to the `Outline` tab) and I'm done. Double click on the *make targets* to compile/clean/install etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Opening the Makefile in the editor and selecting Outline tab? I am still having problems.

Comment: Here is a picture: http://ibin.co/2FwQJIsO5bkU the `Outline` tab is on the right. If it's not there you can open it using `Window->Show View->Outline` from the menu. Then Right-click on the make targets you want and select "Add Make Target" from the little popup. The Make targets appear in the `Make Target` tab.If its not there open it using `Window->Show View->Make Target` from the menu.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I finally solved it. The following must be specified in the build directory  ${workspace_loc:/proj/build} . I don't know why the variable PROJECT_LOC doesn't work when it points to right location and also I don't see where workspace_loc is defined? In Linked Resources, I see the variable WORKSPACE_LOC defined but only when this is in lower case this works. I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It's just enough to untick the `Generate Makefiles automatically`, and specify the `Build directory`.

Also note that

```
 make $(PROJECT_LOC)/build/Makefile
```

actually takes `$(PROJECT_LOC)/build/Makefile` as target (hence the error you see). If you want to specify a particular Makefile use the `-f` option:

```
 make -f $(PROJECT_LOC)/build/Makefile
```

Comment: This still does not work for me unfortunately. It states "No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop".

Comment: So where's your Makefile actually placed?

Comment: My makefile is in the build directory inside the project directory. The absolute address would be like /home/user/Documents/My_proj_/build. I even tried entering the full address into the fields but it's still telling me that there is no makefile found. Strange

Comment: I have actually solved it. In the build directory I Must specify ${workspace_loc:/proj/build} and not use PROJECT_LOC. This I don't understand as where is this workspace_loc variable defined? Under Linked Resources, I see variables defined in Capital Letters and PROJECT_LOC should work?